Changing pcolor of patches depending on the pcolor of neighboring patches
I am trying to get black patches if neighbor patches are green then turn blue and not change the color of already green patches but I'm there yet. The error says:
(Line 13) Expected closing bracket.

My code:
    ask patches with [neighbors4 pcolor green ] 
  [ set pcolor blue ] 

    to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "square"
  ask patches with [(random-float 100) < density]
    [ set pcolor green ]
  ask patches with [neighbors4 pcolor green ] 
  [ set pcolor blue ] 
  ask patches with [pxcor = min-pxcor]
    [ ignite ]
  set initial-trees count patches with [pcolor = green]
  set burned-trees 0
  reset-ticks
end

How to resolve the error?

If you could provide some more code, it will be easy to help you. At leas for me, your code lacks context to fully understant what you are doing and what you intend.

This statement
  ask patches with [neighbors4 pcolor green ] 

does not work. If you look up with you will see that the code in the brackets following it must be a boolean: a comparison that produces a value of true or false.
If what you want is to ask the patches that have only green neighbors, then try this:
  ask patches with [all? neighbors4 [pcolor = green] ] 

(Look up all? to make sure you understand it.)
